# How to resolve this TeamCity Build agent unmet requirement: Exists=>DotNetFrameworkTargetingPack3.0_.* exists

Tags: .net, teamcity

How to resolve this TeamCity Build agent unmet requirement:

```
Exists=>DotNetFrameworkTargetingPack3.0_.* exists
```

I have tried to do Add/Remove Windows features and checked the .NET 3.5 extensibility and recycled the agent service, but it did not work.  I cannot find any specific targeting pack for 3.0+ here, other than applying 3.5 SP1:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by finding where the dependency was coming from and remove it.

It was in the "Runner for gathering JetBrains ReSharper inspection results" and I had almost all of the Target Frameworks checked, including .NET 3.0.  Once I unchecked that .NET 3.0 targeting pack was no longer an agent requirement.